# What is a more striking, more hurried verb for 'press', as in a button?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence: Not much time left. I close my eyes and *press* the PC's on button, willing it to comply.
The reason I don't want to use 'press' is because -while it is commonly employed- it is trite, and does not convey the sense of hurry that I desire. Most thesauri(?) provide synonyms for press, as in to pressure or coerce.

Comment: Pushed the button.

Comment: @vickyace But this still doesn't have a connotation that suggests (to me) hurry. References?

Comment: Jab, pound, hit, strike, tap.  (And if those don't work, look up their synonyms.)

Comment: I love those, Hot Licks! Consider putting them into a more detailed answer?

Comment: How about "punched"? Don

Comment: Mashed the button

Comment: @PhilSweet has my vote .... at least thats what they call frantically pushing buttons to move avatars, cast spells etc in computer games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about **slam** defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slam) as

> to shut, strike, push or put with force.

(I am new, this is literally my first post.)